# how to end a loop in a bat file?

Tags: batch-file

I have seen the following code that opens the notepad until the command window is closed:

```
@ECHO off
:top
START %SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe
GOTO top
```

How can I make a loop so that it only opens the notepad a certain number of times? I have tried with for, but it does not work.

Comment: This should work: `for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do START %SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. The number 5 should be replaced by the number of times you want the command to be run.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "x = 1"
:while1
    if %x% leq 5 (
        START %SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe
        set /a "x = x + 1"
        goto :while1
    )
endlocal
```

Comment: To increment other labguages use `var++` in batch you can use `set /a var+=1` which is equivalent to `set /a var=var+1`